# I get a __NSCFNumber isEqualToString:] error

Tags: objective-c, ios

First of all, sorry for my english, it is not my native langage :)

I'm getting this crash

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68b9d00'".

I saw a lot of similar errors and questions here but the cause were very different than mine.

I have a `NSObject` that I try to pass trough a `prepareForSegue` called Event.
Event is composed by 3 `NSString`, here is my Event.h :

```
@interface              Event : NSObject
{
    NSString*           idEvent;
    NSString*           lat;
    NSString*           lng;
}

@property NSString*     idEvent;
@property NSString*     lat;
@property NSString*     lng;

@end
```

When I get the Event object on the other side, I can output the content of the Event `get(NSLog(@"%@", eventGet.lat); )` and it works fine.
But when I try to put the `"eventGet.lat"` into a `UILabel`, I get the error.

Here is the code where the error occured :
DetailEvent is the view where I get the Event.

DetailEvent.h :

```
@interface  DetailEvent : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latEvent;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lngEvent;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Event* eventGet;

@end
```

And DetailEvent.m :

```
@implementation DetailEvent

@synthesize latEvent            = _latEvent;
@synthesize lngEvent            = _lngEvent;

@synthesize eventToDisplay      = _eventToDisplay;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // works fine
    NSLog(@"Event lat : %@", _eventToDisplay.lat);

    // here is the crash
    _latEvent.text = _eventToDisplay.lat;
}
```

This is confusing me and i would be very grateful!

Thanks !

Comment: Please post the code where you create the `Event` object.  It seems that `lat` is set to an instance of `NSNumber` and not `NSString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

presumably, this is because the variable that is set is an NSNumber, not an NSString (as declared). You could implement the setter for this variable and test the type is NSString when set to find the offenders.

Comment: Oh i just found my mistake thanks to you.
I was setting that NSString with (what i thought was a NSString) but actually a NSInteger.

You were right :)